# Program flow - booleans c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean

With some help I have managed to get the right answer to these questions but I want to get my head around the concepts (i.e. understanding *why* these codes are correct), as understanding is very important and not just memory of syntax.

The first question is *You're given the result of 3 competitions (true = win) , the prize for the first is 1, second is 2, third is 3. Return the total prize amount (you can win any combination of prizes)*

The answer is:

```
 public static int GetTotalPrize(bool first, bool second, bool third)
    {
        var result = 0;

        if (first)
        { result += 1; }

        if (second)
        { result += 2; }

        if (third)
        { result += 3; }

        return result;
    }
```

How does the program know that if you were to win, let's say, the first, second and third prizes, that the total is 6? Or if you were to win the first and third, the total is 4? In other words, how does the code above account for all possible combinations?

The second question is *You're given the result of 3 competitions in one of which you've won (true = win). The prize for the first is 1, second is 2, third is 3. Return the prize amount.*

My answer is:

```
public static int GetPrize(bool first, bool second, bool third) 
{ 
if (first) 
    return 1; 

if (second) 
    return 2; 

if (third) 
    return 3; 

return 0; 
}
```

Without the "return 0;" part at the end, my code was shown as incorrect. Why? As the question states that I have won one of the prizes, so in other words, I am not leaving the competition empty-handed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you to read what `+=` operator does. That would be an answer to your question

Comment: _"Without the "return 0;" part at the end, my code was shown as incorrect. Why?"_ Because its posssible that all bools are false, then you would not return anything. So you had to add the `return 0`. The compiler tried to help and he did

Comment: I'm aware of what it does, but you haven't read my question properly @ Sergey

Comment: Thanks Tim, that makes sense

Comment: @S.Dan: btw, instead of returning `0` for the case that no `bool` is `true` you could also throw an exception. That might be the better option if that is an exceptional case, so should never happen and indicates a bug. So you could replace `return 0;` with `throw new ArgumentException("One of the bools must be true")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, lets take it step by step.

First answer:

```
public static int GetTotalPrize(bool first, bool second, bool third)
{
    var result = 0;

    if (first)
    { result += 1; }

    if (second)
    { result += 2; }

    if (third)
    { result += 3; }

    return result;
}
```

What happens here is the following:

1. The variable `result` is initialized with a value of 0.
2. What follows is a series of if statements. Notice how they are only if and not if-else, meaning they are not mutually exclusive.

   - When an if statement is true, then `result += [some number]` happens. This means that `result` is assigned the value (result + [some number]).
3. Finally, `result` is returned.

Second answer:

```
public static int GetPrize(bool first, bool second, bool third) 
{ 
    if (first) 
        return 1; 

    if (second) 
        return 2; 

    if (third) 
        return 3; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Over here you are told that you have won one of them for sure. If you have not won the first, then you could have won the second or the third. If you have also not won the second, then you must have won the third. So the correct code would be:

```
if (first)
    return 1;
else if (second)
    return 2;
else
    return 3;
```

In this case, the if statements *are* mutually exclusive, since you are told you have won **one** of them.  Unlike the first answer, this syntax *guarantees* that one of the values (1, 2, or 3) will be returned.

The return guarantee is important because you have defined your function as having return type `int`. This means that, no matter what happens in the code, it will *always* return an `int`. In your code, if it weren't for the `return 0`, then there would be no return statement if all ifs were `false`. Of course, you are told that at least one will be true. The compiler however doesn't know that, and so it won't let you compile a function that doesn't fulfill the requirement of always returning a value.

Comment: Perfect explanations. The 'mutually exclusive' parts helped to clear my misunderstandings. Thank you very much

Comment: The second piece of code (if, else if, else) return an error, although it makes perfect sense...?

Comment: @S.Dan The code itself is alright, I made sure before posting. What error do you get?

Comment: I can't seem to see where the error is on Microsoft Visual Studio, but there is a green squiggly line underneath 'bool third' which says 'the parameter 'third' doesn't seem to be used in this method. consider removing it. if the argument must be declared for compiling reasons, rename it to contain only underscore character'.

Comment: @S.Dan What you are seeing is not an error, but a warning. The code will compile even if you leave it as it is. However, VS is telling you that you aren't using `third` anywhere (which you aren't), so it would be best to remove it from the function's parameters.

Comment: I think the logic on your code with `if...else` hides a subtle bug.  If all three arguments are false, it will still return 3.  Even though the problem definition says that one of them will be `true`, if, due to bug elsewhere, all three arguments are false, this code would behave incorrectly. I think I would add `else if (third) return 3;` and have a default of 0, or use a `switch` statement instead.  This would eliminate the bug and also the green squiggly.

Answer (score 1):

The first piece of code works as follows (reading as pseudocode)

---

define a numer named `result`
set its value to `0`

`if` the parameter `(first)` equals `true`, add `1` to `result`

[do this again for `(second)`, and `(third)`, but with their respective numeric values]

return `result`

---

it just counts the score, then returns it.

The second part of your question :

---

you defined your method as guaranteeing to return an `int`. thus, you cannot write the method without following up on that guarantee. you cannot return *NOTHING* (void), or the compiler will complain.

you also cannot return `null` , since an `int` is not nullable.

If we took the logic of your second question, and were told to make it capable of accepting *any* number of rounds, the reason for that last `return` statement might become more obvious:

```
    public static int GetPrize(params bool[] scores)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
        {
            if (scores[i]) // there is no guarantee any of the bools passed along equals true, so we might never hit this return statement.
                return i + 1;
        }

        //if we never hit the first return statment, 
        //we will end up here, and will not have won anything.
        //we still need to return an int, though.
        return 0;
    }
```